# how to map to a SortedList in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have an nHibernate parent child table relationship.  The parent class is currently pulling the children into a List but I want to put them in a SortedList based on an ordering column in the table.  How do I change the NHibernate mapping file to let the system know which column I am ordering on?

The current NHibernate mapping files are:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   namespace="Model.Configuration.Pages"
                   assembly="Model.Configuration">
  <joined-subclass
            table="PageConfigurations"
            name="PageConfiguration"
            extends="Model.Configuration.Configuration.TargetedConfiguration"
            lazy="false">
    <key column="TargetedConfigurationId" />

    <property name="SchemaVersion" />

    <property name="Template" type="System.String" length="50" />

    <property name="PageKey" type="System.String" length="50" />

    <property name="Percentage" />

    <bag name="Controls" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="false" >
      <key column="PageConfigurationId" />
      <one-to-many class="WidgetConfiguration"/>
    </bag>

  </joined-subclass>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

for the parent table and:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   namespace="Model.Configuration.Pages"
                   assembly="Model.Configuration">
  <class name="WidgetConfiguration" lazy="false" table="PageConfiguration_Widgets" discriminator-value="Default">
    <id name="Id"  unsaved-value="0" type="int" >
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <discriminator column="ConfigurationType" />

    <property name="Slot" type="System.String" length="100" />
    <property name="WidgetTypeName" type="System.String" length="100"/>
    <property name="ViewName" type="System.String" length="50" />
    <property name="SlotOrder" type="System.Int32" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

for the child table.

What do I need to add to the parent or child mappings to let them know that the new SlotOrder column should be used as the key field when fetching the WidgetConfiguration into a SortedList.

EDIT: The class that the data is being read into is:

```
public class PageConfiguration : TargetedConfiguration 
{

    public PageConfiguration()
    {
        // replaced by SortedList
        //Controls = new List<WidgetConfiguration>();
        Controls = new SortedList<int, WidgetConfiguration>();
    }

    public string PageKey { get; set; }
    public string Template { get; set; }
    public int? Percentage { get; set; }
    // replaced by SortedList
    //public IList<WidgetConfiguration> Controls { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<int, WidgetConfiguration> Controls { get; set; }
    public int SchemaVersion { get; set; }
}
```

Notice that the `List<WidgetConfiguration>` has been changed to `SortedList<int, WidgetConfiguration>`.  How do I tell NHibernate that when a new item is added to the SortedList that the key value used should be WidgetConfiguration.SlotOrder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NHiberante has nice support for what you would like to get. In fact there is not only one way, there are two:

1) mapping with the `<list>`

Use the list mapping which supports the `<index>` column. this is the same as the internal *index* in the C# used inside the `List<T>` object

Small disadvantage is, that you have to keep that column to be from 0 ... including all numbers. The same as the underlying C# object. but it works

Please see more here: http://ayende.com/blog/4043/nhibernate-mapping-list
and here for indexed collections: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-ofvalues

2) extend the mapping with the `order-by="column_name asc|desc"`

This allows to use some more *user-friendly* column (with some editable value) to be used for the sorting of the list during its loading

Plase, see more here: [6.2. Mapping a Collection](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-mapping)

**EDIT**: to follow the Question Edit

C# `SortedList` mapping is again supported by NHibernate. Please, se the section [6.6. Sorted Collections](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-sorted)

Mapping should look like this

```
<map name="Controls" order-by="SlotOrder" lazy="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
    <key column="PageConfigurationId" />
    <index column="SlotOrder" type="System.Int32"/>
    <one-to-many class="WidgetConfiguration"/>
</map>
```

the `SlotOrder` is now managed by the Parent. It plays the role of the key of the *Controls* `SortedList`. So we should change its mapping to be readonly *(only one editing point in time should exist)*

```
<class name="WidgetConfiguration" ...>
  ...
  <property name="SlotOrder" type="System.Int32" insert="false" update="false" />
```

Having this mapping, we can add new *item* into `Controls` collection:

```
WidgetConfiguration config = ...;
PageConfiguration pageConfig = ...;

pageConfig.Controls[config.SlotOrder] = config;
session.Update(pageConfig);
```

So,

1. we have mapped the *SortedList* (in fact interface `IDictionary<,>`),
2. the `SlotOrder` is used as a key *(inserted, updated by NHibernate)* and
3. available *(as readonly)* on the WidgetConfiguration

That should answer the question about sorting and keys of dictionaries... please, let me know if I did miss something...

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use `<List />` instead of `<Bag />`

```
<bag name="Controls" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="false">
  <key column="PageConfigurationId" />
  <one-to-many class="WidgetConfiguration" />
  <index column="SlotOrder" />
</bag>
```

I notice that you are mapping your collection currently as a `Bag`.  NHibernate supports three kinds of sequenced-collections - `Bag`, `Set` and `List`

List has ordering semantics, as I guess you are aware, but when no ordering is required, you would normally use a `Set`.

Because a `Set` mandates that each item is in a collection only once, it is very easy to remove an item using a single delete statement on that item's Id.  A `Bag` does not mandate collection uniqueness, so the only way for NHibernate to delete an item is to delete everything, and then re-add every item that was not the deleted item.  (The inverse is adding an item to a `Bag` can be faster than using a `Set`, because uniqueness does not have to be enforced)

Ayende (one of the main contributors to NHibernate) posted these a while back:

http://ayende.com/blog/3943/nhibernate-mapping-set

http://ayende.com/blog/4043/nhibernate-mapping-list